# Hide element and show other if browser window width is less than

Tags: javascript, browser, window, hide, show

I'd like to hide an element and show an other element when the user resizes his browser window to a width size that is less than 990px.

- Hide ***largeElement*** when window width is less than 990px
- Show ***smallElement*** when window width is less than 990px

```
<div id="largeElement" style="width:900px;height:100px;background-color:#cc9966"></div>

<div id="smallElement" style="display:none;width:300px;height:100px;background-color:#39c"></div>
```

Does anyone know of a javascript (no jQuery) that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's a plain Javascript solution:

```
<div id="largeElement" style="width:900px;height:100px;background-color:#cc9966"></div>

<div id="smallElement" style="display:none;width:300px;height:100px;background-color:#39c"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
toggle();
window.onresize = function() {
    toggle();
}

function toggle() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
        document.getElementById('largeElement').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('smallElement').style.display = 'block';        
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('largeElement').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('smallElement').style.display = 'none';                
    }    
}
</script>
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4p3nhy8b/

hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :
Using CSS:

```
@media (max-width : 990px){
   #largeElement{
       display : none;
   }
   #smallElement{
       display : block;
   }
}

@media (min-width : 991px){
   #largeElement{
       display : block;
   }
   #smallElement{
      display : none;
   }
}
```

Using Javascript :

```
if(window.innerWidth < 990){
    document.getElementById("largeElement").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("smallElement").style.display = "block";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("largeElement").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("smallElement").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all with [CSS3 media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en)

```
<style>
    @media (max-width: 990px) {
    #largeElement {
        display: none;
    }

    #smallElement {
        display: block;
    }
  }
</style>
```

I know that's not exactly what you asked for but it's the best solution to the problem IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript :

```
function fun(){
   var width = screen.width;
   if( width < 990 ){
     document.getElementById("largeElement").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("smallElement").style.display = "show";
  }
}


load in body  <body onresize="fun()">
```

or

```
window.onresize = fun;
```

Comment: if ii is useful to you . please give up vote and mark correct answer.

Comment: Yes I know, I've already given my up votes and correct answer mark. Thanks for your input though! :)